# Child association error when saving parent object when child item not persisted (in memory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On Rails 4.1.1.

I have a model, `User` and a model `Comment` (example models).

`User` `has_many :comments`.

Take this controller code:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.comments.new({ body: "Hello World!" })
@user.save
```

This causes a validation error on my user object, because the comment has not been persisted to the database.

I have a situation in which I don't want the `comment` to persist to the database, but exist in memory so that `@user.comments` has the additional "record" show up in my view, but doesn't actually exist (as a preview).

For now I'm just removing the entry from the array in the controller, but I'd like to prevent these errors from happening in the future by having a more global method, maybe in a `before_save` hook.

Is this a common problem? Am I experiencing a design pattern that's not "the rails way"?

Comment: This should work fine. Post your model source along with error stack.

Comment: Just don't save it at the end of the method and it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

to save child along with parent..your parent model should have [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

in user.rb

accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments

**Note that the :autosave option is automatically enabled on every association that #accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for.**

so now..you can add/update parent/child very easily

```
params = { member: { name: 'Jack', avatar_attributes: { icon: 'smiling' } } }
member = Member.create(params[:member])
member.avatar.id # => 2
member.avatar.icon # => 'smiling'
```

It also allows you to update the avatar through the member:

```
params = { member: { avatar_attributes: { id: '2', icon: 'sad' } } }
member.update params[:member]
member.avatar.icon # => 'sad'
```